# How can I edit the permissions of a custom form built with SharePoint Designer?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, permissions, custom-form

So, I created a custom new form for a List with SharePoint Designer 2010. But now other users can't view it. I can see it, but I don't even have permissions to change its permissions. How can I work around this and fix the permissions for the custom form?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have custom permissions for the basic list forms (new/edit/view).  Those permissions are driven by the base list permissions, ie, 'New' is restricted to only those that can add items to the list.  What you do have is the notion of a 'default' form for each action.  If you create a custom form that you want to always use, you must set it as the 'default' form for that action (you can do this in SharePoint Designer).  SharePoint will only auto-generate links to the default forms for view/edit/new.  If you only want certain scenarios to use your custom forms, you must direct link to them.

Comment: OK, I set it as the default New form, but users are still unable to access the form.

Comment: What form are they seeing if they click the 'add new item' link (or the 'new item' button in the ribbon)?

Comment: The custom one I made.

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought the problem was that they couldn't view the custom form?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant that is what WILL show up, but no they are unable to access it still.

Comment: I see.  This doesn't sound like a permissions problem.  It sounds more like a javascript issue.  Can you describe a bit more what you mean by 'unable to access'?  Do you mean they can't edit some (or all) fields, can't submit the form, etc?

Comment: They are unable to access the form, it states that they do not have access (i.e. permissions).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12072/discussion-between-wahle509-and-tyshock)